# Tensorflow RNN LM loss not decreasing

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to train a basic unidirectional LSTM RNN language model on PennTree Bank. My neural network runs, but the loss on the test set is not decreasing at all. I'm wondering why is this?

Network parameters:

```
V = 10000
batch_size = 20
hidden_size = 650
embed_size = hidden_size
num_unrollings = 35
max_epoch = 6
learning_rate = 1.0
```

Graph definition:

```
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
  cell_state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, hidden_size), name="CellState")
  hidden_state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, hidden_size), name="HiddenState")
  curr_batch = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[num_unrollings + 1, batch_size])
  lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(hidden_size)
  embeddings = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([V, embed_size], -0.1, 0.1), trainable=True, dtype=tf.float32)
  W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hidden_size, V], -0.1, 0.1))
  b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(V))

  inputs = curr_batch[:num_unrollings,:] # num_unrollings x batch_size
  labels = curr_batch[1:, :] # num_unrollings x batch_size

  input_list = list()
  for t in range(num_unrollings):
    emb = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, inputs[t,:])
    input_list.append(emb)

  outputs, states = tf.nn.static_rnn(lstm, input_list, initial_state=[cell_state, hidden_state])  # outputs: num_unrollings x batch_size x hidden
  cell_state, hidden_state = states
  outputs_flat = tf.reshape(outputs, [-1, lstm.output_size]) # output_flat: (num_unrollings x batch_size) x hidden
  logits = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(outputs_flat, W) + b)   # logits_tensor: (num_unrollings x batch_size) x V
  logits_tensor = tf.reshape(logits, [batch_size, num_unrollings, V])

  targets = tf.transpose(labels)  # targets: batch_size x num_unrollings
  weights = tf.ones([batch_size, num_unrollings]) # weights: batch_size x num_unrollings
  loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.contrib.seq2seq.sequence_loss(logits_tensor, targets, weights, average_across_timesteps=False, average_across_batch=True))
  optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)
```

Session:

```
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
  tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
  cstate = np.zeros([batch_size, hidden_size]).astype(np.float32)
  hstate = np.zeros([batch_size, hidden_size]).astype(np.float32)
  for epoch in range(max_epoch):
    CURSOR_train = 0
    epoch_over = False
    steps = 0
    average_loss = 0.0
    while not epoch_over:
      new_batch, epoch_over = nextBatch()
      feed_data = {curr_batch: new_batch, "CellState:0": cstate, "HiddenState:0": hstate}
      _, l, new_cell_state, new_hidden_state = session.run([optimizer, loss, cell_state, hidden_state], feed_dict=feed_data)
      cstate = new_cell_state
      hstate = new_hidden_state
      average_loss += l
      PRINT_INTERVAL = 200
      if steps % PRINT_INTERVAL == 0:
        print("Avg loss for last {0} batches: {1}".format(PRINT_INTERVAL, average_loss / PRINT_INTERVAL))
        average_loss = 0

      TEST_INTERVAL = 600
      if steps % TEST_INTERVAL == 0:
        # Evaluate the model
        test_over = False
        test_loss = 0.0
        test_batch_num = 0
        print("Testing ... ")
        while not test_over:
          test_batch_num += 1
          test_batch, test_over = nextBatch(setup='test')
          feed_data_test = { curr_batch: test_batch, "CellState:0": cstate, "HiddenState:0": hstate }
          tl, d1, d2 = session.run([loss, cell_state, hidden_state], feed_dict=feed_data_test)
          test_loss += tl
        test_loss = test_loss / test_batch_num
        print("Avg loss on test set: {0}".format(test_loss))

      steps += 1
      sys.stdout.write('\rStep: {0}'.format(steps))
```

The loss on test set is always 320.2430792614422, no matter how long I train it. The loss on the training set does change. 
Thanks in adavance!

Comment: Why do you add `1` to your average loss each training step?

Comment: @chrisz you mean "average_loss += l"? It's lowercased "L" for loss :)

Comment: Wow, I should have gone to bed earlier last night.  If that's the case you're learning rate might be too high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your learning rate is too high, try a learning rate of `0.0005` and just tune around this number.